# How can I retrieve all events from an iPhone calendar?

Tags: iphone, calendar, eventkit

I want to know how to read all events in an iPhone calendar in a programmatic way?

I know the way by which we can retrieve events of known days. The following code retrieves the events for the current date. But how can I retrieve all saved events in an iPhone calendar ie. not depending on dates?

```
NSDate *startDate = [NSDate date];

// endDate is 1 day = 60*60*24 seconds = 86400 seconds from startDate
NSDate *endDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:(86400*1)];

// Create the predicate. Pass it the default calendar.
NSArray *calendarArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:defaultCalendar];
NSPredicate *predicate = [self.eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:startDate endDate:endDate calendars:calendarArray]; 

// Fetch all events that match the predicate.
NSArray *events = [self.eventStore eventsMatchingPredicateredicate];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch events from a user’s Calendar database using three ways : 1)Fetching Events as a Event Store 2)Fetching Events with a Predicate 3)Fetching Individual Events with an Identifier

You can use either Predicate or Identifier, follow the IOS guidelines to see some examles and details.

hopes this Helps.

Answer (score 1):

This bello code is used to get the all calender event from the device calendar
just copy paste this below code you will get the all event

`EventKitUI/EventKitUI.h` -> import this file

```
EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
[store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    if(granted) {
        NSDate* startDate = /* whatever value you want */
        NSDate* endDate = /* whatever value you want */
        NSPredicate *fetchCalendarEvents = [store predicateForEventsWithStartDate:startDate endDate:endDate calendars:nil];
        NSArray *eventList = [store eventsMatchingPredicate:fetchCalendarEvents];
        NSLog(@"allevent:%@",eventList);
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDate* startDate = [NSDate distantPast];
NSDate* endDate = [NSDate distantFuture];
```

Comment: harakiri, your answer wont return any event. I've tried it, also tried
`
NSDate* startDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-10*365*86400 ];
    NSDate* endDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10*365*86400];`